# grails composite key update

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a legacy database and I'm using Grails.  Mistake #1.

It uses compound keys.  Mistake #2.

Given these domain classes:

```
Movie {
    static hasMany = [ roles: Role ]
}
Person {
    static hasMany = [ roles: Role ]
}
Role {
    Movie movie
    Person person
    String foo
}
```

I want to move roles from one person to another, like so:

```
Role x = person1.roles[0]
x.person = person2
save(flush:true)
```

But nothing happens.  At all.  I've turned on trace and debug level logging for hibernate in log4j and it shows no update statement.  But, if I do this:

```
Role x = person1.roles[0]
x.person = person2
x.foo = "i can haz update?"
save(flush:true)
```

An update does happen for foo, but the foreign key pointing to person is not modified, as shown by:

```
DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - update ct_roles set foo=? where movie_id=? and person_id=?
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as 'i can haz update?'
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 999
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - 2
```

Note that person_id 2 belongs to person2, which as yet, has no roles, so the update fails.

So, short of simply deleting the old role and creating a new one attached to the desired person, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: So, I gave up on the update approach and tried the delete old / insert new, but, even that failed.  GORM wouldn't let me oldRole.delete() because it still had an association to the oldPerson.  I couldn't oldPerson.removeFromRoles(oldRole); oldRole.delete() because at that point, oldRole.person == null, and Hibernate tried to delete from TABLE where person_id = null, and failed.  I couldn't reverse the order because "delete row would be recreated during save cascade."

There's a pool of blood on the floor under the brick wall that I've been banging my head against, and that wall's name is GORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
class Role { 
    Movie movie
    Person person
    String fuGorm

    def move(Person newbie) {
        def m = this.movie?.id
        def p = this.person?.id
        def n = newbie?.id

        // bypass GORM and issue a raw SQL update command...
        def q = "update ct_roles set person_id=$n where person_id=$p and movie_id=$m"
        def success = runCommand(q)

        if (success) {
            // the above bypasses GORM, so we should still
            // perform the operation using GORM speak
            // otherwise our objects will be out of sync with the DB.
            // The following EPIC FAILS to update the DB, 
            // but it does update the local Grails domain objects
            this.person.removeFromRoles(this)
            this.person = newbie
            newbie.addToRoles(this)
        }
        return success
    }
    def runCommand = { query ->
        def db = new Sql(dataSource)
        db.execute (query)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: 

person1.removeFromRoles(role) *//role is the role object from which person is to be removed*
role.person = person2

Should work.

Comment: Thanks, good idea, but computer says "no (cough)."  I implemented your idea which seemed to be progress in the right direction because suddenly I got ConcurrentModificationException because I was modifying the list of roles as I was iterating through it.  But, once I changed my code to iterate over a duplicate of the list, it still fails in exactly the same way :-( In an ideal world, "should work" would work.

Comment: so you just added the `addToRoles` code.. my answer deserves an upvote :P

Comment: Sure, you deserve an upvote.  Thanks for the help! But I don't have enough rep -- Stackoverflow won't let me.  

But no, addToRoles was not the solution.  The soul of the solution is the raw SQL update. GORM completely fails to do anything to the underlying tables.  Which is almost understandable as one should never, ever alter a primary key, composite or otherwise.  Stupid legacy DB.  The addToRoles is simply ensuring that Grails has an accurate picture of the new state of the database.